# Zebra ZM600 installation on RHEL 5.6 with no RHN subscription, and i get no Java VM error

Tags: linux, jvm, redhat, zebra-printers

I have RHEL 5.6 X86_65 server.
When I installs a file, it gives me this error:

```
#./zecinstall.bin
Preparing to install...
Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
No Java virtual machine could be found from your PATH
environment variable.  You must install a VM prior to
running this program.
```

I have:

## where is java

`java: /usr/bin/java /etc/java /usr/lib/java /usr/share/java`

## which java

`/usr/bin/java`

Answer (score 0):

From the troubleshooting part of the manual (ZebraLinkTM Enterprise Connector User Guide)

> Java Version Issue:
>
> • When running zecinstall.bin, it reports that no
>   Java virtual machine can be found.
>
> • Java crashes when attempting to
>   run ZEC.
>
> Solution:
>
> • Verify that the correct version of Java is
>   installed by running “java –version”. It should report “JavaTM SE
>   Runtime Environment” and not “OpenJDK Runtime Environment”.
>
> • Install
>   Java from Sun’s website (not the open-source version of Java).

It looks like it needs Oracle Java, and won't run unless it's installed.